# React LocalStorage issue not stored in localstorage

Tags: mysql, reactjs, local-storage

I am using Local Storage for my login page
but my variables not storing in the local storage I don't know why....

I am using the following code on my button click....

But the APi i am using is correct... It works fine

res.data.status gives true or false,Inside Axios .then => If is used for correct username and password and else is used for incorrct user

This is my Code:

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/project/login.php?name='+name+"&price="+price;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar',"hi")
    await axios.post(url, formData)
    .then(res => {
      if(!res.data.status){
        localStorage.setItem('username', name);
       alert(res.data.message);
      }else{
       alert(res.data.message);
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your variable is not stored in the localStorage. that's because of the condition you have. also as you're sure that your API is working fine and you can successfully make a request and receive a response. then the issue is with the condition. because from your code. you're making conditions only if the request is not successful. you don't have the condition for success.

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/project/login.php?name='+name+"&price="+price;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar',"hi")
    await axios.post(url, formData)
    .then(res => {
      if(!res.data.status){ <= remove the !
        localStorage.setItem('username', name);
       alert(res.data.message);
      }else{
       alert(res.data.message);
      }
    })
}
```